# Relating bordism groups of $\Omega_{d}^{Spin_c}$ and $\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times SU(N))/\mathbb{Z}_2}$ to that of $U(N)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, stable-homotopy, spectral-sequences, cobordism

I felt that the [earlier question may be too challenging](https://mathoverflow.net/q/311910/27004), so let me provide a different angle and more infos to tackle an easier and separate problem.

Let us consider a more explicit a short exact sequence:
$$
1\to SU(n)\to  U(n)\to U(1) \to 1,
$$
where the normal subgroup $N=SU(n)$, $Q=U(1)$, and $G=U(N)$ can be continuous Lie groups in general (or finite groups).

We see that $ {U} (n)$ is related to $ {SU} (n)$ and $ {U} (1)$ by
$$
  {U} (n)=\frac{  {U} (1)\times   {SU} (n)}{\mathbb{Z}_n}
$$
where ${\mathbb{Z}_n}= {\mathbb{Z}}/({n \mathbb{Z}})$, a finite Abelian cyclic group of order $n$. This is the case because both $U(1)$ and ${SU} (n)$ shares the same subgroup
$${\mathbb{Z}_n}=\{ \exp(\frac{2 \pi i }{n}j) \cdot \mathbb{I}_{n\times n}\}$$
where $j \in \mathbb{Z} \mod n$. Let us take $N \in$ even integer, thus 
$${\mathbb{Z}_n} \supset \{1,-1\}={\mathbb{Z}_2}.$$

- Say we **already get the data** and the computations of the bordism group 
  $$
  \Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times Q)/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times U(1))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{Spin_c},
  $$
  where ${(Spin \times Q)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$ means the modification of the $Spin$-structure to a new ${(Spin \times Q)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$-structure. Here 
  the $Spin$ and $Q$ shares a normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_2$ that was mod out, such that
  $$
  Spin/\mathbb{Z}_2= SO,
  $$
  or more explicitly 
  $$
  Spin(d)/\mathbb{Z}_2= SO(d),
  $$
  where we omit the dimension $d$ through this post in the $Spin \equiv Spin(d)$.
- Suppose **we also know the data** and the computations of the bordism group 
  $$
  \Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times N)/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times SU(n))/\mathbb{Z}_2},
  $$
  where ${(Spin \times N)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$ means the modification of the $Spin$-structure to a new ${(Spin \times N)/\mathbb{Z}_2}$-structure.  Here 
  the $Spin$ and $N$ shares a normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_2$ that was mod out.

> **Question** How can we compute 
>   $$\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times G)/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times U(n))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=?
> $$ 
>   where the precise extension is given,
>   based on the previously known information of $\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times Q)/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{Spin_c}$ and $\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times N)/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times SU(n))/\mathbb{Z}_2}$?

For example, we know the $\Omega_{d}^{Spin_c}$ data as follows:
$$\Omega_{0}^{Spin_c}=\mathbb{Z},$$
$$\Omega_{1}^{Spin_c}=0,$$
$$\Omega_{2}^{Spin_c}=\mathbb{Z},$$
$$\Omega_{3}^{Spin_c}=0,$$
$$\Omega_{4}^{Spin_c}=\mathbb{Z}^2,$$
and let us say we can take some specific $N \in$ even say as $N=4$.
$$\Omega_{0}^{(Spin \times SU(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\mathbb{Z},$$
$$\Omega_{1}^{(Spin \times SU(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\mathbb{Z}_2,$$
$$\Omega_{2}^{(Spin \times SU(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\mathbb{Z}_2,$$
$$\Omega_{3}^{(Spin \times SU(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=0,$$
$$\Omega_{4}^{(Spin \times SU(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\mathbb{Z}^2,$$
How do we determine

> $$\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times G)/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times U(n))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=\Omega_{d}^{(Spin \times U(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2}=?
> $$
>
> How about other even $n$?